# How to find $\int_{\Gamma} \cos z \sin z dz$ where $\Gamma = \pi t + (1-t)i$ for $t \in [0,1]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find $\int_{\Gamma} \cos z \sin z dz$ where $\Gamma = \pi t + (1-t)i$ for $t \in [0,1]$?

I subbed in to get $$(\pi-i)\int_0^{1} \cos (\pi t + (1-t)i) \sin (\pi t + (1-t)i) dt$$ which I found to be $-\frac{1}{2} \sin^2(i)$ using a substitution of the form $u=\sin (\pi t + (1-t)i)$.

Is the correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have a primitive *everywhere*

$$\int \cos z\sin z\;dz=\frac12\int2\sin z\cos z\;dz=\frac12\int\sin 2z\;dz=-\frac14\cos 2x+K$$

we then get at once that

$$\int_i^\pi\cos z\sin z\;dz=\left.-\frac14\cos 2z\right|_i^\pi=-\frac14(1-\cos 2i)$$

and observe that (trigonometric identities)

$$\frac14(\cos 2i-1)=\frac14(\cos^2i-\sin^2i-1)=\frac14(1-2\sin^2i-1)=-\frac12\sin^2i$$